# Export a matrix to Excel

Tags: excel, r

I made a matrix and I want to export it to Excel. The matrix looks like this:

```
           1         2         3         4         5         6         7
2  0.4069264                                                            
3  0.5142857 0.2948718                                                  
4  0.3939394 0.4098639 0.3772894                                        
5  0.3476190 0.3717949 0.3194444 0.5824176                              
6  0.2809524 0.3974359 0.2222222 0.3388278 0.3974359                    
7  0.2809524 0.5987654 0.3933333 0.4188713 0.4711538 0.3429487          
8  0.4675325 0.4855072 0.4523810 0.4917184 0.3409091 0.4318182 0.4128788
9  0.3896104 0.5189594 0.4404762 0.2667549 0.5471429 0.3604762 0.3081502
10 0.4242424 0.4068878 0.3484432 0.2708333 0.4766484 0.3740842 0.4528219
11 0.3476190 0.3942308 0.2881944 0.3228022 0.4711538 0.2147436 0.3653846
12 0.6060606 0.3949830 0.2971612 0.3541667 0.5022894 0.3484432 0.4466490
13 0.4675325 0.5972222 0.6060606 0.3670635 0.4393939 0.3939394 0.3695652
14 0.4978355 0.4951499 0.4480952 0.4713404 0.3814286 0.3147619 0.4629121
15 0.4632035 0.4033883 0.4508929 0.3081502 0.4728571 0.3528571 0.4828571
16 0.3766234 0.5173993 0.4771825 0.4734432 0.5114286 0.3514286 0.4214286
17 0.3939394 0.5289116 0.3260073 0.3333333 0.5663919 0.2330586 0.3015873
18 0.3939394 0.3708791 0.2837302 0.4102564 0.3392857 0.2559524 0.4123810
19 0.3160173 0.5727041 0.4885531 0.3056973 0.4725275 0.3827839 0.3346561
20 0.3333333 0.5793651 0.4257143 0.4876543 0.4390476 0.2390476 0.3131868
21 0.5281385 0.3762755 0.4052198 0.2997449 0.4180403 0.2898352 0.4951499
22 0.3593074 0.3784014 0.4075092 0.2423469 0.4908425 0.3113553 0.3430335
23 0.5281385 0.5875850 0.4404762 0.4634354 0.6071429 0.3763736 0.3747795
24 0.3549784 0.6252381 0.5957341 0.4328571 0.4429563 0.4429563 0.3422619
25 0.4242424 0.4931973 0.5054945 0.2142857 0.4670330 0.4285714 0.4312169
26 0.3852814 0.5671769 0.4954212 0.4073129 0.3736264 0.4890110 0.4523810
27 0.5238095 0.3269558 0.5187729 0.4051871 0.5412088 0.5155678 0.5859788
28 0.3160173 0.1904762 0.3205128 0.3384354 0.3429487 0.3173077 0.5123457
29 0.2380952 0.4468537 0.5196886 0.4536565 0.4491758 0.4491758 0.4634039
30 0.4545455 0.4295635 0.4080087 0.4791667 0.3474026 0.3019481 0.4627329
31 0.2857143 0.3988095 0.3397436 0.3443878 0.4294872 0.2756410 0.3456790
32 0.3636364 0.3027211 0.3772894 0.3452381 0.4413919 0.3388278 0.3818342
33 0.3333333 0.4482402 0.4080087 0.4275362 0.2888199 0.4047619 0.4301242
34 0.5411255 0.4825680 0.4043040 0.4417517 0.4748168 0.3850733 0.3708113
35 0.3160173 0.5476190 0.4230769 0.3979592 0.3653846 0.3397436 0.2283951
36 0.4603175 0.4653209 0.4778912 0.5170807 0.3928571 0.4508282 0.4254658
37 0.3939394 0.1955782 0.2490842 0.4047619 0.2490842 0.3516484 0.4559083
38 0.3463203 0.4660494 0.4300000 0.4157848 0.3833333 0.2233333 0.2788462
39 0.5844156 0.4668367 0.3809524 0.3843537 0.4803114 0.3008242 0.5026455
40 0.5454545 0.4902211 0.3740842 0.2946429 0.5279304 0.2971612 0.3293651
41 0.5800866 0.3758503 0.5073260 0.5136054 0.3598901 0.5393773 0.4823633
42 0.4458874 0.3937390 0.3785714 0.4686949 0.3768315 0.3127289 0.4954212
43 0.6536797 0.5740741 0.5533333 0.4453263 0.4866667 0.5400000 0.4358974
44 0.5887446 0.5548469 0.4308608 0.3949830 0.5462454 0.3411172 0.5136684
45 0.4069264 0.4357993 0.4308608 0.3830782 0.4308608 0.3795788 0.4025573
46 0.5974026 0.3826531 0.3672161 0.3954082 0.4441392 0.3159341 0.5141093
47 0.2554113 0.4196429 0.4262821 0.4961735 0.2788462 0.3301282 0.3055556
```

I tried the command:

```
WriteXLS("my matrix after i converted it to data.frame", "test.xls")
```

but I got this error:

> The Perl script 'WriteXLS.pl' failed to run successfully.

I googled it but I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Any reason why you can't just use `write.csv`?

`write.csv(mymatrix, "test.csv")`

Import it in Excel and you're set!

PS: I assume you're not putting quotes around your variable name in the `WriteXLS` call, right?

Comment: There are many reasons not to work with CSVs, but more when working with non-numeric input too. If you're working with nontechnical people it usually leads to charset confusions and hard-to-track import problems especially when it comes to different decimal and separation characters which vary by locale.

Comment: I doubt you work with nontechnical people or non-ASCII data a lot and I envy you ;-) There's also these annoying conventions about German Excel using semicola for input (not configurable), but American Excel using commas (not configurable). TSV is a little bit more portable if you have to go low-tech.

Comment: @Ruben: Yes you can configure it! I live in France and I changed the preferences of Excel on all of the computers in my office to use points instead of commas. It's somewhere in the preferences, locale settings or something.

Comment: That's the decimal sign, not the separator. I'm pretty sure you can't change the separator on a per-import basis, maybe if you change the locale of the OS or Excel completely (not very user-friendly). Anyway, it's possible using OpenOffice, but Excel doesn't automatically do it correctly which is enough to confuse my coworkers and enough to make me want to give them a file that they can just open with a good old double-click.

Answer (score 11):

One other option on Windows (which seems a reasonable assumption given that you are using Excel):

You can write a matrix (or data frame) to the clipboard using a command like:

```
write.table(mymat, 'clipboard', sep='\t')
```

Then just go into Excel, click in the cell that you want to be the top left cell, then do a paste and your matrix is there (the `sep='\t'` is important for Excel to interpret it correctly).

This is similar to other answers, but you don't need an intermediate file on disk.

Answer (score 7):

You could also check [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) if you do not mind the Excel 2007 format, as xlsx does not depend on Perl (though depends on rJava).

After loading the packge via `library(xlsx)` just try the following:

```
write.xlsx(USArrests, "/usarrests.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see what is going on here exactly. Might be several things.

I think the easiest way to write a matrix to excell is by using `write.table()` and importing the data in excell. It takes an extra step but it also keeps your data in a nice format.

If `foo` is your matrix:

```
write.table(foo,"foo.txt")
```

If you get an error maybe trie coercing the object to a matrix:

```
write.table(as.matrix(foo),"foo.txt")
```

Does the matrix contain values in the upper triangle as well? Perhaps making a full matrix works:

```
foo<-foo+t(foo)
write.table(as.matrix(foo),"foo.txt")
```

But these are all just random shots in the dark since I don't have a matrix to work with.

EDIT: In response to the other answer, you can remove the column and rownames with `col.names=FALSE` and `row.names=FALSE` in both `write.table()` and `write.csv()` (which are the same function with different default values).

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, after reinstalling strawberry perl : after debugging the WriteXLS function in R, I found out the the perl module Text::CSV_XS was missing from my fresh new install. I installed this module from the DOS command line :

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Text::CSV_XS
```

After this, WriteXLS was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
upper # matrix name

write.xlsx2(upper,file = "File.xlsx",  sheetName="Sheetname",col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE, showNA=TRUE)
```